# What is the permissible distance from weather head to roof edge?

Tags: electrical

I have been told by Southern California Edison (SCE), that my weather head is too far from the edge of my roof to put a new breaker box in place of the old one. what is the permissible distance from weather head to roof edge?

Comment: Please clarify. Not sure what you mean by edge of the roof. Also, give your location, or at least your utility. Specs are usually available online to find out this information.

Comment: Can you provide a photo or two?

Answer (score 1):

Without actually seeing the installation, I'm simply guessing here. They *could* be referring to National Electrical Code 230.24(A)ex. no. 3.. Which says that the clearance above a roof can be reduced to 18 in. if the service conductors do not overhang the roof by more than 6 ft., **and** there's less than 300 volts between conductors, **and** the service conductors terminate at a through-the-roof raceway.

So basically, if the service conductors have to overhang the roof by more than 6 ft., this exception can no longer be applied. Without this exception, the service conductors must be 8 ft. above the roof.

You'd either have to extend the weather head up, to keep the conductors 8 ft. above the roof. Or move the weather head, so that the conductors do not have to overhang the roof by more than 6 ft..

> ## National Electrical Code 2014
>
> ### Chapter 2 Wiring and Protection
>
> #### Article 230 Services
>
> **II. Overhead Service Conductors**
>
> **230.24 Clearances.**
>
> **(A) Above Roofs.** Conductors shall have a vertical clearance
>   of not less than 2.5 m (8 ft) above the roof surface. 
>   The vertical clearance above the roof level shall be maintained
>   for a distance of not less than 900 mm (3 ft) in all
>   directions from the edge of the roof.
>
> *Exception No. 3: Where the voltage between conductors
>   does not exceed 300, a reduction in clearance above only
>   the overhanging portion of the roof to not less than 450 mm
>   (18 in.) shall be permitted if (1) not more than 1.8 m (6 ft)
>   of overhead service conductors, 1.2 m (4 ft) horizontally,
>   pass above the roof overhang, and (2) they are terminated
>   at a through-the-roof raceway or approved support.*